# HTMLのbuttonタグでonclick属性が効かない

Tags: javascript, html

緊急で人が書いたHTMLを修正しなければならないのですが、私は仕様も技術的背景も知りません。
この時点で褒められた仕事のやり方ではないと思いますが、そこはとりあえずスルーでお願いします。

HTMLには

```
<button>foo</button>
```

というボタンがあり、このボタンが何もしていないというのが問題になっています。
とりあえずgoogle.comというサイトに飛べばいいとして、

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>テスト</title>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
  <button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com'">ボタンテスト</button>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

というHTMLを作り、これは同じサーバー、同じディレクトリ、同じブラウザーできちんと動作することを確認しました。
しかし、動かないボタンがあるHTMLに

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://google.com'">ボタンテスト</button>
```

を追加すると、ボタン[ボタンテスト]は表示し、マウスをホバーするとカーソルが指の形になるのですが、クリックしてもジャンプが起こりません。

cssをbutton、btnという文字列で検索しましたがはかばかしいヒントは得られませんでした。
どこかでonclickが抑制されていると思うのですが、どこをどう変えれば動作するでしょうか。
（私が変更したボタンの部分だけでその制限が解除されるとかだと最もうれしいです）

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: おそらくどこをどう変えれば動作するかはHTMLやJSやCSS全体を確認しないとわからないため難しい質問になる印象です。どちらかというとフロントエンドのデバック方法を聞いたほうがよいかと、例えば[buttonにフックされているJSイベント]等やbuttonに適用されているCSSの確認の仕方など

Comment: ありがとうございます。時間切れになったので、週明けに作った人に正攻法で聞くことになりました。HTML/CSS意外と深いな！

Answer (score 1):

お世話になります。こういうことだったらしいです。
問題の画面は、以下のような構成でした。

```
【表題】
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
＜ボタン＞
```

この表題および文章は、HTMLの別の場所にあるUIによって切り替わり、長さも可変です。

```
【表題】
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
＜ボタン＞
```

で、表題／文章の部分は、すべて重ね合わせて表示されており、切り替えのUIによってアクティブなものは不透明に、イナクティブなものは透明になっていました。
で、文章が短い場合は、他の長い透明な文章によってボタンが覆い隠されてしまい、無効になっていました。
よって、最も長い文章よりもさらに下に、ただ１つのボタンが来るように、HTMLを書き直しました。

```
【表題】
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
　文章・・・
　文章・・・

＜ボタン＞
```

表示している表題／文章に応じて、ボタンの飛び先も変える仕様でしたが、これは、表示／非表示の属性を切り替えるjQueryを改造して、リンクを書き換えることにしました。
ということで、HTML/CSSの問題というよりは仕様の問題でした。
どうもスミマセン。